# Using Boost::asio mulithreading to dump container contents

Tags: c++

I am using the skeleton of this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html
echo example and have modified it to suit my project, so you can refer to this codebase. In addition to what the code does, i.e you type a message on client - > sent to server - > echoed back to client, I also store the message sent in a separate container on server side. I would like to dump the contents of that container into a text or binary file, but would like to do so on a separate thread, not the one being used by the client-server if that makes sense. The tricky part is that it needs to do this dump every 10 seconds or so. Just using basic **std::thread** I can obviously do it, but its the every 10 seconds part that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html

Comment: Why do you want to do the dump in a separate thread?

Comment: Thank you **Alan**, cant believe the solution was the first ever tutorial I did on boost which is the async timer, works like a charm so far, thank you!! **Jakob** its a task that has been give to me, probably to see some boost::asio async timer skills that I now have developed in the last 10 mins lol